What mermaid-looking creature is on the blackboard in the Charms class within Hogwarts Legacy?
When you're in the Charms class in Hogwarts Legacy, then in one of the corners in the room, there's a blackboard containing a drawn image of some kind of creature. It almost looks a little like a mermaid of some sort.


What is this creature?

My guess is a Merperson:


Merpeople were creatures resembling half-human, half-fish hybrids (though they were not, in actuality, half-breeds). Like humans, merpeople came in a variety of appearances.

